# I want to create a muxer for mixing a audio and video that i get by parsing the MPEG-DASH URL

Tags: java

My problem statement is I am trying to access a live stream of video, which I am receiving in the form of MPEG-DASH URL. With this URL, I am able to get chunks of video and audio data separately in the form of m4v and m4a  extensions respectively.

I am pushing the bytes that I get from each segment to a server (currently separately for both audio and video). I want that when I use the MPD URL (MPEG-DASH URL), I can mux the small chunk of audio and video segment bytes on the fly and send the result bytes to the server that contains the mixed audio and video.

The problem is I am able to get the video and audio file separately. I need to get only one file at the server end that has both audio and video.

I don't want to use "**FFmpeg**". Is there any native way in JAVA to implement this muxing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. I stumbled in your same situation and I finally decided to build my `ffmpeg` java wrapper. It is quite simple as it just requires standard JRE libraries. It would work like following:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg.exe -i ...");
// consume process.getErrorStream()            
// consume process.getInputStream()
int exitVal = process.waitFor();
// exitVal = 0 means process was executed correctly
```

You must have `ffmpeg.exe` available on your path and always have to consume your streams, otherwise you may get the main process stuck infinitely. As you can provide parameters to the command, you can later use the files produced by `ffmpeg` quite easily.

Comment: Thanks Squake. One more question I have. I know that ffmpeg is a utility that takes a single process to run. My question is what if I want to extend my application to handle larger videostreams and also concurrent requests. So, is that scalable enough to use ffmpeg utility for larger applications

Comment: `ffmpeg` is very high CPU consuming, so if you start putting too many concurrent process I suppose it starts suffering. Even more if you fork execution from Java. I use it as a single process for such reason, so I suggest to keep this bounded to the number of CPUs you have available on your machine: you can use some library out there if you're interested - https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity